# invoking closure within another closure?

Tags: php

PHP seems very inconsistent and (compiler) fails to generate the logic. Let's start our investigation, first with a simple set of JSON data.

```
[
{
    "customer": "cust01",
    "assembly": "assem01",
    "date_received": "02-08-2015",
    "time_received": "09:15",
    "date_completed": "02-23-2015",
    "time_completed": "10:27"
},
{
    "customer": "lov_01",
    "assembly": "lov_02",
    "date_received": "lov_03",
    "time_received": "lov_04",
    "date_completed": "lov05",
    "time_completed": "lov_06"
}
```

]

Then in the PHP, we retrieve an array of that data

```
    $t_json_string = file_get_contents($t_json_file_path);
    $t_json_arr = json_decode($t_json_string, true);
```

Assume we retrieve post values in an array like this

```
$t_new_entry = [ 
    "customer"      => "lov_01", 
    "assembly"      => "lov_02",
    "date_received" => "lov_03",
    "time_received" => "lov_04",
    "time_completed"=> "lov_05",
    "time_completed"=> "lov_06"
];
```

and the goal is to verify as if new entry exists in the json array yet, by a condition whether both arrays have more than 2 similar values, for that I'm using $t_count to count the number of similar occurrences.
I wrote up 2 methods for checking that while passing the same data into the data pool.

```
// $t_boo = $db_entry_check($t_new_entry, $t_json_arr); echo $t_boo; 
// true, $t_count shows 3.

   $t_bool = $db_entry_exist($t_new_entry, $t_json_arr); echo $t_bool; 
// False. It has to be true with the $t_count printed out at 3.
```

The first one employs call_user_function_array, which I tested and it works so I commented it out. Code for it here:

```
$db_entry_check = function($needle, $haystack){
    $t_exist = 'false';
    $t_count = 0;

    function h_loop (&$t_count, $value, $array){
        foreach ($array as $key => $val){
            if (is_array($val)){
                h_loop($t_count, $value, $val);
            } else {
                echo "<br/> --- value: ". $value. "<br/> --- val: ". $val . "<br/><br/>";
                if ($val === $value){
                    $t_count += 1;
                    echo "<br/>" . $t_count . "<br/>";
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function n_loop (&$t_count, $arr, $array){
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
            if (is_array($value)){
                n_loop($t_count, $value, $array);
            } else {
                if ($t_count > 2) continue;
                call_user_func_array('h_loop', [&$t_count, $value, $array]);
            }
        }
    }
    n_loop($t_count, $needle, $haystack);
    echo "<br/>" . $t_count . "<br/>";
    if ($t_count > 2) $t_exist = 'true';
    return $t_exist;
};
```

The second one is my attempt to use lambdas on every component functions. I tried playing around putting *$value*, *$array*, and *$t_count* into *use()* part as those variables exist within the scope of *$db_entry_exist* for data binding & dependencies injection. When it comes to considering parameters (for the function) vs dependencies (for the use) Of the *h_loop*, I find it confusing, what an entire mess in PHP efforts to implement concepts of Javascript.

No matter what parameters I am passing onto the function part and no matter what variables got injected in the *use()* part. Many variations have been tested but none of them work. I usually get an error of **'Function name must be a string'**. Invoking a closure within another closure in PHP seems not working as the logic in Javascript. It fails me whenever I tries to pass *$h_loop($t_count, $value, $array);* or *echo $factorial(5);* in the else part of the *n_loop* function. What I don't understand is that *$db_entry_exist* itself is a lambda (Closure as what PHP calls it) and *n_loop* function can be called inside without any error but calling/invoking a grandchild (*h_loop*) function by the same approach does not work, often resulting in the same error above.

```
    $db_entry_exist = function($needle, $haystack){
    $t_exist = 'false';
    $t_count = 0;
    // n_loop($t_count, $needle, $haystack);

    $h_loop = function (&$t_count, $value, $array) use (&$h_loop) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $val){
            if (is_array($val)){
                h_loop($t_count, $value, $val);
            } else {
                echo "<br/> --- value: ". $value. "<br/> --- val: ". $val . "<br/><br/>";
                if ($val === $value){
                    $t_count += 1;
                    echo "<br/>" . $t_count . "<br/>";
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    $factoral = function($n) use (&$factoral) {
      if ($n <= 1)
        return 1;
      else
        return $n * $factoral($n - 1);
    }; // source: https://gist.github.com/superic/8290704

    $n_loop = function (&$t_count, $arr, $array) use (&$n_loop) {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
            if (is_array($value)){
                $n_loop($t_count, $value, $array);
            } else {
                if ($t_count > 2) continue;
                $h_loop($t_count, $value, $array);
            }
        }
    };

    /*$n_loop = function ($arr, $array) use (&$n_loop, &$t_count){
        // echo "<br/> --- nloop.t_count: " . $t_count . "<br/>";
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
            if (is_array($value)){
                $n_loop($value);
            } else {
                if ($t_count > 2) continue;
                // $h_loop($value, $array);
            }
        }
    };*/

    $n_loop($t_count, $needle, $haystack);
    echo "<br/>" . $t_count . "<br/>";
    if ($t_count > 2) $t_exist = 'true';
    return $t_exist;
};
```

and here is the link to view my entire code:

```
<script src="http://ideone.com/e.js/YjLkZF" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

To sum up, there are primarily 2 issues I don't understand and can't figure:

1. *$n_loop* is invoked fine within *$db_entry_exist* method but *$h_loop* isn't.
2. In the context of *$db_entry_exist*, how to pass and pass what variables to the *function()* and pass what as dependencies to the *use()* part.

   $n_loop = function (&$t_count, $arr, $array) use (&$n_loop){}
   // ------ OR ------- many other variations are there too.
   $n_loop = function ($arr, $array) use (&$n_loop, &$t_count){}

Please investigate the code and let me know your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: You're talking about having static function like this `code`$h_loop = static function (&$t_count, $value, $array) use (&$h_loop) { } `code` OR not using $h_loop as a pointer ? If your point is about conflict in naming convention --> function and variable names within the scope of $db_entry_exist are not affected by those of $db_entry_check. I can even comment out all $db_entry_check (the working code).

Answer (score 1):

You have two misconceptions in your code that are affecting your understanding.

First: PHP does not actually have nested functions. When you say:

```
function outer()
{
    function foo() {}
    function bar() {}
}
```

what you are really saying is, when `outer()` is called, define `foo()` and `bar()` in the global scope. This means that once you call `outer()` once, *anyone* (not just `outer()`) can call `foo()` and `bar()`. This also means that calling `outer()` a second time results in a `Cannot redeclare foo()` error.

Second: Closures in PHP do not automatically close over *any* variables in their parent scope. Any variables intended to be part of the closure must be explicitly included in the `use()` list. This means that when you write:

```
$n_loop = function (&$t_count, $arr, $array) use (&$n_loop) {
    //...
            $h_loop($t_count, $value, $array);
    //...
};
```

the call to `$h_loop` will always fail, because in the scope of that function, there is no variable named `$h_loop`. If you add `$h_loop` to your `use()` list, then you will be able to call it as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm looking into fixing the code in one of the following ways, not sure which could work to resolve the problem:
1. Move nested functions out of the outer function and wrap all the functions with class SuperClosure{} to make them all private
2. set the inner functions private by doing: private function foo(){}
3. OR doing: protected function foo(){}

and insert $h_loop to my use(), like this
$n_loop = function (&$t_count, $arr, $array) use (&$n_loop, $h_loop) {}

Comment: I'm also seeking a better way to do a CRUD manipulation of JSON & JSON decoded arrays right in PHP: checking if entry exists, delete/update that entry, insert a new entry/record if not exist. Can you give good reference to study upon?

Comment: protected and private visibility indicators only work on class methods, so just adding those to your first set of functions will not work. Moving the functions into a class would seem to be your best bet. CRUD manipulation of JSON is a completely different topic, and would best be discussed in a separate question.